# unknown error parsing query using dates in query

Tags: soql, query

Trying to execute next query.

```
Select OPPORTUNITYID__C, OM_R1_Consulting_Start_Date__c, OM_R1_Consulting_End_Date__c 
FROM Opportunity 
Where OM_R1_Consulting_Start_Date__c > OM_R1_Consulting_End_Date__c
```

And getting error meassege : unknown error parsing ... as result
What's wrong in my query?

Both are of Date type custom field.of type: '12/17/2015'

Comment: query is looking fine, post the screen shot from developer console so that we can get some additional detail. you might have typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOQL does not allow comparison operators between fields, your query:

```
Select OPPORTUNITYID__C, OM_R1_Consulting_Start_Date__c, OM_R1_Consulting_End_Date__c 
FROM Opportunity 
Where OM_R1_Consulting_Start_Date__c > OM_R1_Consulting_End_Date__c
```

This expression is not allowed (unlike in some other database query languages):

```
Where OM_R1_Consulting_Start_Date__c > OM_R1_Consulting_End_Date__c
```

The general solution to this is to add a formula field in your object like this;

```
hasInvalidStartDate__c type = Boolean with whatever conditions make the startDate invalid
```

and then query where clause is

```
Where hasInvalidStartDate__c = true
```